# Entity collection by class

Tags: c#, collections, entity

I have several classes: `User.cs`, `Permission.cs`, and so on... all of them are children of `BaseCore.cs` where all the main logic is.

Here is my `dbContext` class (simplified):

```
public class MyContext : DbContext {
    public MyContext() : base("AppEntityDB") {
        System.Data.Entity.Database.SetInitializer(new DropCreateDatabaseAlways<MyContext>());
    }

    public virtual DbSet<User> Users { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<Permissions> Permissions { get; set; }
}
```

Now I am creating `baseListForm.cs` that will be parent of all ListForms (windows form aplication)

I want `baseListForm` to have all basic functions like `SaveData();` `EditData()` and `LoadData()`;

Here is my `BaseListForm` class (simplified):

```
public partial class BaseListForm : Form {
  private BaseCore _classType;
  public virtual void LoadList() {
      //I want here to load the collection of Mycontext() depending
      // on what which class it calls. eg. if User.cs calls then i want
      // to call DbSet<User> Users collection (accessible - _classType.Users)
      var LoadCurrentClass = ClassType.
  }
}
```

So I want to somehow select the corresponding collection from `MyContext()` for `this.GetType();` class.

Answer (score 0):

If you mean to say that 1 form has access to 1 dataset only then you can use generics.

You can add more functionalities other than my example. Normally you would create a repository or a unit of work class for CRUD operations on the database but this would restrict your form to access 1 DbSet. I hope you get the idea.

**Form Base**

```
public abstract class FormBase<T> : Form
    where T : BaseCore
{
    private ApplicationDbContext _db = new ApplicationDbContext();

    /// <summary>
    /// Accessor for the DbSet
    /// </summary>
    protected DbSet<T> DbSet
    {
        get { return _db.Set<T>(); }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Inform the DbContext of the changes made on an entity
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="entity"></param>
    protected void UpdateEntry(T entity)
    {
        _db.Entry(entity).State = EntityState.Modified;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Save changes on the DbContext
    /// </summary>
    protected void SaveData()
    {
        _db.SaveChanges();
    }
}
```

**User Form**

```
public partial class frmUser : FormBase<User>
{
    public frmUser()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        User user = this.DbSet.FirstOrDefault(); // Get first user record
        user.Name = "New Name"; // Set new name value
        this.UpdateEntry(user); // Inform DbContext that user has changed
        this.SaveData(); // Save the changes made to the DbContext
    }
}
```